# Why is Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey, TValue) always returning true?

Tags: dictionary, authentication, boolean, keyvaluepair, trygetvalue

I'm trying to use `Dictionary.TryGetValue()` to search a dictionary for a username and password hash, if it matches authenticate the user, if not do something else.

The problem I'm having is that anytime the hash value does not match what's in the dictionary it returns true anyways, maybe because it matched the username key?
Is it expected behavior to return true if only the key but not that value matches?

I've included my method and user output below. I'm printing the hashes for troubleshooting purposes.

### Here's example user output where the hash matches and then it doesn't:

**It does not change behavior if the hash doesn't match the first time**

PASSWORD AUTHENTICATION SYSTEM

Please select one option:

1. Establish an account
2. Authenticate a user
3. Exit the system

Enter selection: 1
Enter your username: username

Enter password:
username, 5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8]

PASSWORD AUTHENTICATION SYSTEM

Please select one option:

1. Establish an account
2. Authenticate a user
3. Exit the system

Enter selection: 2
Enter username you would like to authenticate
Username: username

Enter password:
**5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8**
**5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8**
Successfully authenticated as username

PASSWORD AUTHENTICATION SYSTEM

Please select one option:

1. Establish an account
2. Authenticate a user
3. Exit the system

Enter selection: 2
Enter username you would like to authenticate
Username: username

Enter password:
**152f66d0fe3a409590ec40fea1ee037cefb4549a1f511defd16824117a768b1d**
**5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8**

Successfully authenticated as username

### Below is the authentication method

```cs
        static void authUser(string userName)
        {
            if (!passDB.ContainsKey(userName))
                Console.WriteLine($"Username \"{userName}\" does not exist.");
            else if (passDB.ContainsKey(userName))
            {
                string secret;
                string testHash;
                int tryCount = 4;

                do
                {
                    secret = HidePassInput();

                    SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create();
                    testHash = GetHash(sha256Hash, secret);
                    Console.WriteLine(testHash);
                    if (passDB.TryGetValue(userName, out testHash))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(testHash);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Successfully authenticated as {userName}\n");
                        tryCount = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tryCount--;
                        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to autheticate as {userName}. {tryCount} more tries left.\n");
                    }
                    
                } while (tryCount > 0);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are misunderstanding the use of the `TryGetValue` method.

The first parameter is the key for which you want to get its value. The second parameter is an `out` parameter. If the key exists, its value will be assigned to the variable that you've used as argument to the `out` parameter. Whatever value was held by `testHash` is overwritten.

`TryGetValue` does not receive a value that you are looking for. It only receives a key. It returns true if that key is found, otherwise false. The value of the found key is assigned to the `out` variable.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I'll have to find another combination of methods/properties to achieve what I'm looking for.